# hyper-v not recognizing linux integration services on CentOS7

Tags: hyper-v, centos7

Why does the Hyper-V host not recognize LIS on the CentOS 7 machine?

Hyper-V Manager Version 6.3.9600.16384

`uname -r` shows `3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64`

`lsmod` shows `hv_storvsc`, `hv_netvsc`, `hv_utils` and `hv_vmbus` loaded.

`modinfo hv_utils` shows version 4.0.7

`dmesg` shows the host recognized: `Hyper-V Host Build:9600-6.3-17-0.17039; Vmbus version 3.0` and other messages that seem to indicate data is received from the host, such as `hyperv_fb: Screen resolution: 1152x864, Color depth: 32`

However, `Get-VM | ft Name, IntegrationServicesVersion` shows a blank field while other VMs show a version. The Hyper-V Manager "Integration Services:" field is likewise blank, and the SCVMM "VM Additions" column for the VM shows "0.0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have the parts of Hyper-V support which are included with the Linux kernel.  You don't have the daemons installed which talk to Hyper-V to report guest-side status and such.

Here's a link which discusses installing these.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531026.aspx